# dockerfile stat var/www/html: file does not exist

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Today i trying to ues the Dockerfile instructions to create a new image.
my dockerfile

```
FROM 1275178869/base_image_apache_php_mysql:sjx 

COPY file /var/www/html     

RUN rm /var/www/html/index.html

EXPOSE 80
```

Then I run the command

```
docker build -t sql:sql .
```

in step 2
copy failed like:

```
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat var/www/html: file does not exist
```

is that mean the  mirror source i use
···
FROM 1275178869/base_image_apache_php_mysql:sjx
···
There is no path /var/www/html

Comment: You can only copy files that are inside your "build context": the directory you pass as the final argument to `docker build`.

Comment: What does it mean. Does this mean that /var/www/html should be in my "build context"?

Comment: If you `docker build ... .`, with `.` as the last argument, then the `file` on the left-hand side of `COPY` must be in the `.` host directory (that is, the current directory).  The error message says it's not there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let give you some possible solutions

Use COPY with ./ and also with the file extension

```
COPY ./file.txt /destination/path
```

In the case if it is a directory, use ADD

ADD ./file  /destination/path

Also make sure not to have **file** in your .dockerignore

Comment: I have try ADD ./file /destination/path。 It still don't work. I'm wondering whether something is wrong with /var/www/html. Because after I changed the file name to 'file1', the error message change to "stat file: file does not exist"  instead of "stat var/www/html: file does not exist". Is that mean the 'file' on the left-hand side of COPY is in the . host directory.

Comment: I checked your docker image (1275178869/base_image_apache_php_mysql:sjx ) it has /var/www/html path and test in my envierment worked fine. Can you please tell me what was the error once you added ADD ./file /var/www/html

Comment: I think i found the problem; probably because I added some #Chinese note after the ADD ./file /destination/path.I don't know why, but after I removed the following note the ADD ./file /destination/path. executed fine.Thank you very much.

Comment: Fantastic! At least I could help you with something.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the accepted answer